# Documentation for Proguard

Tags: java, obfuscation, proguard

Can anyone point me towards the un-obfuscated version of the Proguard documentation?

I've seen the obfuscated version here: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/#manual/

Comment: Too localized?! Because the manual is understandable outside the UK?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html ? There is unfortunately not much more available.